# Open workbooks and copy sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I need help with a macro that will open workbooks in the same folder and copy the Whole sheet in each workbook to a workbook where my macro is at.

There are 4 different workbooks and they all have a different number of sheets and I need to have all the sheet from each workbook in one.

I just started programming and get and error object required 424 on the line that says:
Set wsSheet = wbRegularesBruto.Sheets("Movimentacao").Cells.Copy

Can someone please guide me to resolve this issue. Does anyone know of an easier way to get all these sheets copied into the TH Macro Workbook?

```
Option Explicit
Sub TrainingHoursMacro()

Dim wbTHMacro As Workbook, wsRegulares As Worksheet, wsRegularesDemitidos As Worksheet, wsTempActivos As Worksheet, wsTempJA As Worksheet, wsTempFit As Worksheet, _
wsTempDemitidos As Worksheet, wsPresenceSystem As Worksheet, wsResultados As Worksheet, wsDLList As Worksheet, wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim wbRegularesBruto As Workbook, wsMovimentacao As Worksheet, wsDemitidos As Worksheet
Dim wbTemporariosBruto As Workbook, wsTemporariosAtivos As Worksheet, wsJAAtivos As Worksheet, wsAprendizesFit As Worksheet
Dim wbPresenceSystem As Workbook, wsTPCC As Worksheet

Set wbTHMacro = Workbooks("Training Hours Macro.xlsm")
Set wsRegulares = wbTHMacro.Sheets("Regulares")
wsRegulares.Cells.ClearContents

Set wbRegularesBruto = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="H:\BX-HR\BX-INDUSTRIAL RELATIONS\HR REPRESENTATIVES\PRIVATE\HRSSC\Brazil\Training Hours Macro\Regulares Bruto.xls")
If Not wbRegularesBruto Is Nothing Then
  Set wsSheet = wbRegularesBruto.Sheets("Movimentacao").Cells.Copy

  wsSheet.Cells.Copy wsRegulares.Range("A1")
Else
  Exit Sub
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the `.Cells.Copy` from the end of the problem line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set wsSheet = wbRegularesBruto.Sheets("Movimentacao").Cells.Copy
```

`wsSheet` is a Worksheet object. I assume you want to assign it to this sheet, so you would use:

```
Set wsSheet = wbRegularesBruto.Sheets("Movimentacao")
```

You could then use `Cells.Copy` after this. You can't do both in one statement.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and the example... both worked... but now I get another error as I continue to program stating: Object Variable or with block variable not set on this line: `wsSheet.Cells.Copy wsRegularesDemitidos.Range("A1")`

Set wsSheet = wbRegularesBruto.Sheets("Movimentacao")
    wsSheet.Cells.Copy wsRegulares.Range("A1")
Else
  Exit Sub
End If

`Set wsSheet = wbRegularesBruto.Sheets("Demitidos")
wsSheet.Cells.Copy wsRegularesDemitidos.Range("A1")
    
  Exit Sub`

Comment: I am not sure what line you are referring to, as you've copied the whole code. Just ensure that you use `Set` for each of your WorkBook and WorkSheet objects before you attempt to do something with them.

Comment: `wsSheet.Cells.Copy wsRegularesDemitidos.Range("A1")` its the last line in the code...

Comment: As I said, you need to `Set` wsRegularesDemitidos to some worksheet. It doesn't currently refer to anything.

Comment: OK I will try something out here... Thanks for the previous answer I will keep working on this one...